# Why does the RegQueryValueEx() function return ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND while trying to read from a registry key?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, registrykey

System: Windows 7 32bit
Language: C++

I have tried to access register `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\Scsi\\Scsi Port 0`, key `Driver` (type `REG_SZ`) -- no problem.

The same for reading from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM`, all keys (types `REG_SZ`) got slashes, for example `\Device\Serial0`.

While reading such keys it always returns 2 (no such file) with following example code:

```
HKEY hKey = 0;
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
char buf[255] = {0};
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);

if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
{
  auto ret = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("\Device\Serial0"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize );
  // ret always == 2 for key with slashes
--- CUT ---
```

What is the proper way to read key values with slashes in name?

---

**Above has been properly answered by Cody Gray.**

---

**Below another issue.**

---

Im getting the same problem when Im using variable instead of a text string.
Iv considered both approaches with single and double slashes:

```
HKEY hKey = 0;
DWORD keyType = REG_SZ;
TCHAR buf[255] = {0};
DWORD bufSize = sizeof(buf);

QSettings winReg("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM", QSettings::NativeFormat);
auto comsKey = winReg.allKeys();

FOREACH( auto com, comsKey )
{
  // FOREACH - boost macro
  // comsKey = QList<QString> (list of key names) [from Qt framework]
  // com = QString (single key name) [from Qt framework]
  if( RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
  {
    wchar_t* keyw = new wchar_t();
    //com.replace("/", "\\\\"); <- checked both variants commented and not commented; com == /Device/Serial0 so im converting to \\Device\\Serial0
    int size = com.size();
    mbstowcs( keyw, com.toStdString().data(), size );
    //auto ret = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("\\Device\\Serial0"), 0, &keyType, (LPBYTE)buf, &bufSize ); // <- this works!
    auto ret = RegQueryValueExW( hKey, (LPCWSTR)&keyw, 0, &keyType, (LPBYTE)buf, &bufSize ); // <- this one not works!
```

I have tried all variants with "\Device..", "/Device", "\Device", etc.

Comment: @Werner, no, the `RegQueryValueEx` function *only* queries the value of a registry key. Values are the name/data pairs stored within keys. So you can't pass it a nested path of keys as you describe because values don't have paths. Admittedly, the terminology is quite confusing, Raymond Chen attempted to explain it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/04/9394113.aspx).

Comment: [`RegGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew), on the other hand, can query a value of a nested subkey.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to escape the slashes, just like you did in the first line...

```
if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
{
  auto ret = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("\\Device\\Serial0"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize );
  // ret always == 2 for key with slashes
```

If you don't, the `RegQueryValueEx` function can't find the specified key, and it returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (== 2).

---

But there's another problem. You should be declaring the buffer array as type `wchar_t` (or `TCHAR`), rather than `char`:

```
TCHAR buf[255] = {0};
```

Otherwise, the `RegQueryValueEx` function is going to attempt to fill the array with a Unicode string read from the specified registry key, and you're going to get something unreadable.

Comment: buf should be declared as TCHAR, not as wchar_t. ReqQueryValueEx does not care about how buf is declared, the returned value depends on whether RegQueryValueExA or RegQueryValueExW is called.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, that's technically true. But Windows applications haven't been compiled as ANSI (non-Unicode) for over 10 years. A lot of people don't care to use the macros anymore, and it's hard to blame them.

Comment: Your answer is rather optimized to give the OP a hard time.  C++11 syntax, WMI is quite unfriendly in C++, serial ports are not plug-and-play devices.

Comment: @Hans: I copied the `auto` syntax from the original question; I assume he's not using Microsoft's compiler. What would you suggest as a better approach than WMI? I'm almost certain that reading this from the registry is not the right way.

Comment: Reading that registry key to discover COM port names is the prescribed way.  The .NET SerialPort.GetPortNames() method uses it for example.

Comment: @CodyGray: auto syntax is compatibile with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 compiler.